# What does the NA introduced by coercion error mean in p.adjust(x, method = "BH") function in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use this function:

p.adjust(x, method = "BH")

When I put my file name in for "x"...its a text file so "filename.txt" I get this error:

Warning message:
In p.adjust("miRNA2.txt", method = "BH") : NAs introduced by coercion

Any tips or tricks? I'm super new to this so please be gentle.

Comment: the function expects the x to be `a numeric vector of p-values` not a file - you need to read your file in first, then use the correction. The warning means it took your file name as a string, tried to convert it to a number, and got an error, making it an NA.

Comment: Thanks. Let me see if I can solve this problem now.

Comment: I converted the file to a numeric vector and now my error is: object cannot be coerced to type 'double'   Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to do something like `x<-read.csv('myfile.txt'); p.adjust(x, method = "BH")` You can;t simply refer to a file inside a string - you need to explicitly read it in. You will need to figure out your text file format etc, in order to make this work.